# Help mounting an External HDD for use with Media Server

Tags: mount

I'm almost finished setting up my Plex Media Server, but I've gone wrong somewhere trying to mount my External 1.5TB (sdc)... It's mounted to ubuntu, but Plex can not see the files...

Not sure what to do so I'll give `sudo fdisk -l`, `sudo blkid`, and `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`, hopefully that will be enough to spot the problem.

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2f16dad8-494b-4cce-b3d6-aead00238b17 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=e881ffcf-37ab-43d1-b1a4-eb00581b7110 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=543E2FD13E2FAB46 /mnt/media_sdb1 ntfs-3g defaults 0 0

UUID=E46014BE6014997E /media/external ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0


$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="2f16dad8-494b-4cce-b3d6-aead00238b17" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="e881ffcf-37ab-43d1-b1a4-eb00581b7110" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="I LOVE YOU !" UUID="543E2FD13E2FAB46" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdc2: LABEL="KILLUMINATI - ONE" UUID="E46014BE6014997E" TYPE="ntfs"

$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007f670

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   471801855   235899904   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       471803902   488396799     8296449    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       471803904   488396799     8296448   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x47d9be29

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  2930274303  1465136128    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT
```

Comment: Thank you for editing it chaos... Hope I can find some help solving this... Has to be a permissions issue, right?

Comment: If Plex creates a user/group, then yes it may be a permissions issue. I had that exact problem with MythTV. Created a directory on the external and gave mythtv owner/group permissions to it and that fixed it.

Comment: Forgive my noobishness, but can you elaborate on how you created this directory, and what I need to do to give the permissions to plex for that drive? I think I'm doing what the tutorial I'm following has instructed, but no dice....

Comment: If you could edit your post to include a link to the tutorial, that would be helpful.

Comment: Are you still able to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this page](http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/Plex_Media_Server-Linux_Permissions_Guide) to give a good rundown on permissions on Linux systems as it relates to Plex. From reading it, it does appear that Plex creates a user `plex` to run under. If you have configured Plex to store your media files on the external, Plex needs permission to access the files stored there. I would not recommend making Plex the owner of the external drive; create a directory on the external to store media and and point Plex to that directory (you will have to do that in your Plex configuration).

```
sudo mkdir /media/external/plexmedia
sudo chown plex /media/eternal/plexmedia
sudo chmod 755 /media/external/plexmedia
```

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion... It seemed to take in the terminal... But it didn't register with plex... I'll try rebooting and check back...

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding Plex to the plugdev group.**

Open a terminal (Press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) and enter

`sudo gpasswd -a plex plugdev`

Verify that plex was added to the plugdev group by entering:

`groups plex`

which should display what groups plex belongs too. Next, reboot the computer and start plex to verify this corrected the problem.